# Cannot launch emulator on Linux (Ubuntu 15.10)

Tags: android-emulator, ubuntu-15.10

I try to launch emulator but it outputs into log:

```
libGL error: unable to load driver: r600_dri.so 
libGL error: driver pointer missing 
libGL error: failed to load driver: r600 
libGL error: unable to load driver: swrast_dri.so 
libGL error: failed to load driver: swrast 
X Error of failed request:  GLXBadContext   
Major opcode of failed request:  155 (GLX)
Minor opcode of failed request: 6 (X_GLXIsDirect)
Serial number of failed request:  47
Current serial number in output stream:  46 
libGL error: unable to load driver: r600_dri.so 
libGL error: driver pointer missing 
libGL error: failed to load driver: r600 
libGL error: unable to load driver: swrast_dri.so 
libGL error: failed to load driver: swrast 
X Error of failed request:  GLXBadContext
Major opcode of failed request:  155 (GLX)
Minor opcode of failed request:  6 (X_GLXIsDirect)   
Serial number of failed request:  47   
Current serial number in output stream:  46 
libGL error: unable to load driver: r600_dri.so 
libGL error: driver pointer missing 
libGL error: failed to load driver: r600
libGL error: unable to load driver: swrast_dri.so 
libGL error: failed to load driver: swrast 
X Error of failed request:  BadValue (integer parameter out of range for operation)   
Major opcode of failed request:  155 (GLX)   
Minor opcode of failed request:  24 (X_GLXCreateNewContext)   
Value in failed request:  0x0   
Serial number of failed request:  33   
Current serial number in output stream:  34 
QObject::~QObject: Timers cannot be stopped from another thread emulator: WARNING: Increasing RAM size to 1GB
```

How to fix it? I read topics with similar errors but it doesn't help me.

Comment: find here a convenient solution without the extralines given in this answer: [https://github.com/rimian/cordova-ember-android]

Answer (score 79, accepted):

Take a look at

https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=197254

in particular items #3 and #19. This is a workaround rather than a true solution, but it got me moving again. You will have to adjust the command  for:

- the location of the `libstdc++.so.6` file on your system - I used `locate libstdc++.so.6` to find this
- the path to the emulator executable
- the name of your emulator

so my command was

```
LD_PRELOAD='/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6' ~/Android/Sdk/tools/emulator -netdelay none -netspeed full -avd Nexus_5_API_21
```

This then launches the emulator, and you can select it in the 'Device Chooser' dialogue when you run your app.

Comment: Thank you! But in my case OS doesn't see fglrx package although I installed it and it worked. But after system updates I got this bug. I reinstalled this package and it became work again :) Sorry for English.

Comment: The fix outlined in post #23 from the link allowed my emulator to launch on Ubuntu 16.04, but the emulator screen displays only black.

Comment: I solved the problem by the ugly way:   `cp /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6 $ANDROID_HOME/tools/lib/libstdc++/libstdc++.so.6`

Comment: In case it's helpful, you can find the name of the emulator with: `LD_PRELOAD='/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6' ~/Android/Sdk/tools/emulator -list-avds`

Answer (score 170):

Using the libstdc++.so.6 that is available in your system instead of the one bundled with the android sdk solves this issue.

- The emulator has a switch `-use-system-libs` to do this.

  `~/Android/Sdk/tools/emulator -avd Nexus_5_API_23 -use-system-libs`
- Alternatively you can set the `ANDROID_EMULATOR_USE_SYSTEM_LIBS` environment variable to `1` for your user/system. This has the benefit of making sure that the emulator will work even if you launched it from within Android Studio.

More details: https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=197254#c15

Comment: And after that in your Android Studio will appear a connected device (in this case Nexus_5_API_23) when you try to run your app.

Comment: This is the best answer imo as the emulator can be launched properly via a shell script without having to move or link the existing sdk libraries.

Comment: on Ubuntu 16.10 `export ANDROID_EMULATOR_USE_SYSTEM_LIBS=1` has to be added to `$HOME/.profile`

Comment: unknown option: -use-system-libs :(

Comment: @JaroslavZáruba what's your android emulator version?

Comment: @GregDan: or to `/etc/environment`

Comment: This does not work for me on Debian. I still need to remove `lib64/libstdc++` folder to make emulator working. This is ridiculous, why do they keep shipping built in libs to mess everything. Switch should be opposite than currently ism system libs should be used by default.

Answer (score 123):

```
$ cd Android/Sdk/emulator/lib64/libstdc++
$ mv libstdc++.so.6 libstdc++.so.6.bak
$ ln -s /usr/lib64/libstdc++.so.6
```

it's worked for me

Comment: It looks like I had to install the libstdc++ and only after that I was able to run the simulator, Thanks for your help !

Comment: my libstdc++.so.6 as located at /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6

Comment: @Joshua - Correct. For Ubuntu 17.10+, you need the following for the last step $ ln -s /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6

Comment: Worked for me. I'd love to know what broke it though.

Comment: This solution works for me. Emulator broke after update from Ubuntu 16.04 to 18.04. Thanks!

Answer (score 51):

I have a similar error in Ubuntu 16.04 64-bit.
For me the answer **#23** solution works great
https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?can=2&start=0&num=100&q=&colspec=ID%20Status%20Priority%20Owner%20Summary%20Stars%20Reporter%20Opened&groupby=&sort=&id=197254

```
$ cd $ANDROID_HOME/android-sdk-linux_x86/tools/lib64/libstdc++
$ mv libstdc++.so.6 libstdc++.so.6.bak
$ ln -s /usr/lib64/libstdc++.so.6 $ANDROID_HOME/android-sdk-linux_x86/tools/lib64/libstdc++
```

Comment: This worked for me. You may have to look in different directories for your android sdk though. Mine was found at `/home/daniel/Android/Sdk/tools/lib64/libstdc++`

Comment: Yes, the section path before the "/tools" can be vary depending on the User names and the Sdk installation folder.

Comment: confirm working, in ubuntu xenial the path is  /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6

Comment: thank you....this was the solution as well in ubuntu 16.10, same path as in the above comment    ln -s /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6 ~/Android/Sdk/tools/lib64/libstdc++

Answer (score 29):

Use "Software" in the Emulated Performance Graphics option, in the AVD settings. Very simple solution.

Comment: It's a simple but it's very slow :)

Comment: Work on ubuntu 16 64bit, just dropdown select :) 10x

Comment: That was the ONLY solution which worked for me (Ubuntu 16.04LTS)

Answer (score 20):

i do this and it's working

```
cd ~/Android/Sdk/emulator/lib64/libstdc++ 
mv libstdc++.so.6 libstdc++.so.6.bak
ln -s /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6 libstdc++.so.6
```

Comment: I had this bug due to my video driver, I reinstalled it later and all begun to work. I forgot about this bug already, it's very weird that someone still has problems cuz in search a lot of solutions including this topic.

Comment: i just have this bug 10 min ago :)

Answer (score 10):

better locate your system default libstdc++.so.6 using the command
locate libstdc++.so.6

And Then Take a back up of the android sdk version of the file in ~/Android/Sdk/tools/lib64/libstdc++/

And create a soft link for libstdc++.so.6 with the same name in the above path replacing the existing one pointing to the default file in the system

This way we do not need restart the emulator every time from command line.

Answer (score 9):

Try to change graphics option in Emulator settings:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

I was also having a lot of problems to launch AVD on my machine. Struggled with using system libs, creating symlinks to local libraries, etc...

What really made it work for me was to install the nvidia drivers with

```
sudo apt install nvidia-340
```

My distro (note I'm not using Ubuntu 15.10):

```
$ uname -a
Linux ruapehu 4.4.0-38-generic #57-Ubuntu SMP Tue Sep 6 15:42:33 UTC 2016 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

$ cat /etc/issue
Ubuntu 16.04.1 LTS \n \l
```

Make sure you check the nvidia package suitable for you, as Ubuntu offers different flavors. For instance:

```
$ sudo apt list "nvidia-[0-9][0-9][0-9]" 
Listing... Done
nvidia-304/xenial 304.131-0ubuntu3 amd64
nvidia-331/xenial 340.96-0ubuntu3 amd64
nvidia-340/xenial,now 340.96-0ubuntu3 amd64 [installed]
nvidia-346/xenial 352.63-0ubuntu3 amd64
nvidia-352/xenial 361.42-0ubuntu2 amd64
nvidia-361/xenial,now 361.42-0ubuntu2 amd64
```

I tested the list in a bottom-up strategy, from 361 until I found one that worked (340, in my case).

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

In my case (Ubuntu 16.10 64-bit, Android Studio 2.3) libs were located in another place. So commands are:

```
/home/myusername/Android/Sdk/emulator/lib64/libstdc++

➜  libstdc++ ll
total 9,3M
-rwxr-xr-x 1 myusername myusername 4,6M мар 21 00:09 libstdc++.so.6
-rwxr-xr-x 1 myusername myusername 4,6M мар 21 00:09 libstdc++.so.6.0.18

➜  libstdc++ mv libstdc++.so.6 libstdc++.so.6.bak
➜  libstdc++ mv libstdc++.so.6.0.18 libstdc++.so.6.0.18.bak
➜  libstdc++ ln -s /usr/lib32/libstdc++.so.6 /home/myusername/Android/Sdk/emulator/lib64/libstdc++ 
➜  libstdc++ ln -s /usr/lib32/libstdc++.so.6.0.22 /home/myusername/Android/Sdk/emulator/lib64/libstdc++ 

➜  libstdc++ ll
total 9,3M
lrwxrwxrwx 1 myusername myusername   25 мар 29 13:18 libstdc++.so.6 -> /usr/lib32/libstdc++.so.6
-rwxr-xr-x 1 myusername myusername 4,6M мар 21 00:09 libstdc++.so.6.0.18.bak
lrwxrwxrwx 1 myusername myusername   30 мар 29 13:19 libstdc++.so.6.0.22 -> /usr/lib32/libstdc++.so.6.0.22
-rwxr-xr-x 1 myusername myusername 4,6M мар 21 00:09 libstdc++.so.6.bak
```

And now emulator is launched from AVD manager normally.

Answer (score 0):

I had the similar problems with using `i965_dri.so` and `swrast_dri.so`, I wasn't able to change to software graphics in the GUI.

So I went to the emulator's folder (`Show on Disk` link in AVDM) and found the `config.ini`

Here I just changed the following line to stop it from using GPU:

```
hw.gpu.enabled=no
```

Answer (score 0):

This is fixed in Android Emulator 27.2.9. See the first fix listed here:
https://developer.android.com/studio/releases/emulator#fixes

Answer (score -1):

> $ cd ~/Android/Sdk/emulator/lib64/libstdc++
>   $ mv libstdc++.so.6 libstdc++.so.6.bak
>   $ ln -s /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6 libstdc++.so.6