# Not allow me to run the emulator on android studio for lack of driver in the operating system Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: android-studio, android-emulator, android-virtual-device, ubuntu-16.04

i'm using android studio 2.0 in ubuntu 16.04 and  don let me run the emulator avd   because apparently it lacks a driver. How i could solve this problem?

this is the exception that throws after  i  run the emulator

```
Cannot launch AVD in emulator.

Output:
libGL error: unable to load driver: radeonsi_dri.so
libGL error: driver pointer missing
libGL error: failed to load driver: radeonsi
libGL error: unable to load driver: swrast_dri.so
libGL error: failed to load driver: swrast
X Error of failed request:  GLXBadContext
  Major opcode of failed request:  155 (GLX)
  Minor opcode of failed request:  6 (X_GLXIsDirect)
  Serial number of failed request:  49
  Current serial number in output stream:  48
libGL error: unable to load driver: radeonsi_dri.so
libGL error: driver pointer missing
libGL error: failed to load driver: radeonsi
libGL error: unable to load driver: swrast_dri.so
libGL error: failed to load driver: swrast
X Error of failed request:  GLXBadContext
  Major opcode of failed request:  155 (GLX)
  Minor opcode of failed request:  6 (X_GLXIsDirect)
  Serial number of failed request:  49
  Current serial number in output stream:  48
libGL error: unable to load driver: radeonsi_dri.so
libGL error: driver pointer missing
libGL error: failed to load driver: radeonsi
libGL error: unable to load driver: swrast_dri.so
libGL error: failed to load driver: swrast
X Error of failed request:  BadValue (integer parameter out of range for operation)
  Major opcode of failed request:  155 (GLX)
  Minor opcode of failed request:  24 (X_GLXCreateNewContext)
  Value in failed request:  0x0
  Serial number of failed request:  33
  Current serial number in output stream:  34
QObject::~QObject: Timers cannot be stopped from another thread
emulator: WARNING: VM heap size set below hardware specified minimum of 128MB
emulator: WARNING: Setting VM heap size to 384MB
```

Would appreciate any response!

Comment: Same here (I'm using Android Studio 2.1, Xubuntu 16.04, have a NVIDIA  GT218 GeForce 210, KVM activated)

Comment: I do not understand that, because when I was ran correctly on buntu 14.04

Comment: The [ask ubuntu](http://askubuntu.com/) community would have been a good place for this question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Well , i found a solution for this problem.
I don't know what it's wrong with Android Studio but he can't execute the any emulator and the solution for me nowadays is execute the emulator by command,after that you install a emulator using android studio execute the command below because you need to have the emulator, in my case Nexus_5_API_21.

```
LD_PRELOAD='/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6' ~/Android/Sdk/tools/emulator -netdelay none -netspeed full -avd Nexus_5_API_21
```

i don't remeber exactly where i found this solution but i think it's on google forums

Answer (score 4):

I am also using Android Studio 2.1 with Ubuntu 16.04

There is an answer from [this stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35911302/cannot-launch-emulator-on-linux-ubuntu-15-10/36625175) question that worked perfectly.

A few things to note: My $ANDROID_HOME was different then this one. I had to take out the `android-sdk-linux_x86` in the filename. Also there was multiple versions of libstdc++.so.6 libstdc++.so.6.0.18 and libstdc++.so.6.0.21. I still used the libstdc++.so.6 and it worked perfectly

```
$ cd $ANDROID_HOME/android-sdk-linux_x86/tools/lib64/libstdc++
$ mv libstdc++.so.6 libstdc++.so.6.bak
$ ln -s /usr/lib64/libstdc++.so.6 $ANDROID_HOME/android-sdk-linux_x86/tools/lib64/libstdc++
```

Comment: In my case, I just deleted `$PATH_TO_ANDROID_SDK/tools/lib64/libstdc++/libstdc++.so.6` and everything started working fine. You may also fine more variants there, like 6.0.18 and 6.0.21, delete them too.

Answer (score 2):

What I did to solve this on my Xubuntu 16.04 was :

- Check what my graphics card is with: `lspci | grep VGA`

  - answer: some NVidia model
- Check what graphics driver I was currently using with: `sudo lshw -C video | grep driver`

  - answer: the Nouveau default, free software driver
- Installed proprietary NVidia driver : go to Main search menu (depending on your Unity, or Gnome, or Xfce) > Additional drivers > switch from "Nouveau" to "NVIDIA binary driver - version 3XX (proprietary, tested)
  [image]

  - *I know there are other (horribly complex and fallible) [ways to download and install NVidia drivers](https://askubuntu.com/a/451248/148090), but the cool and simple way worked for me*
- Reboot

And my Android emulator errors were gone :)

Comment: I'm still having the same

Comment: Solved my issue. Couldn't figure out why Hardware rendering failed, but Software worked. Completely forgot about the installing the Nvidia driver.