# Android emulator won't launch on Ubuntu 17.04

Tags: android, emulation, ubuntu-17.04

I've downloaded Android Studio 2.3.3 and currently, I'm trying to run basic Hello World activity which is automatically generated. When I try to launch emulator, it does not launch.

Is it a known bug or just wrong configuration? I was also surprised that there is just version 2.3.3 for Linux.

Comment: i had the same problem. This answered worked for me https://stackoverflow.com/a/43536258/653856

Comment: Wow, it helped. Can you please explain me, what it did?

Comment: not sure. just take a look at  other answers as well. Also whenever i update  emulator i also need to repeat the steps to launch emulator

Comment: it replaces the broken c++ standard library that comes with the emulator with the one that comes with Ubuntu.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The emulator comes with a bundled libstdc++.so file. In some cases the bundled file is not compatible with your system. Using the libstdc++.so.6 that is available in your system instead of the one bundled with the Android SDK may solve this issue.

To use the system's libstdc++.so file, edit the .profile file, located in  your home folder, and append this at the end of the file:

```
export ANDROID_EMULATOR_USE_SYSTEM_LIBS=1
```

From the documentation of [Android Studio Environment Variables reference](https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line/variables.html#envar):

> Contains a value of 0 (default) or 1. A value of 1 means to use the system's libstdc++.so file instead of the one that comes bundled with the emulator. Set this environment variable only when the emulator does not start on your Linux system because of a system library problem. For example, some Linux Radeon GL driver libraries require a more recent libstdc++.so file.
>
> **Note:**
>
> There is no guarantee that setting this environment variable to 1 will make the emulator runnable. It is a work-around for system library issues that affect a very small number of Linux users.

Answer (score 1):

Option **-gpu swiftshader_indirect** helps me in my case. Full command to start emulator

```
/android_sdk/tools/emulator @NEXUS_API_27 -verbose -no-boot-anim -gpu swiftshader_indirect
```

Where NEXUS_API_27 name of virtual device. You can get it here:

```
/android_sdk/tools/bin/avdmanager list avd
```