# Can't run Emulator on Intellij Ubuntu

Tags: android, linux, ubuntu, intellij-idea, react-native

I have installed both Android studio and IntelliJ on my Ubuntu(16.04) lap.I have created Nexus_5X_API_24 from Android studio.So i can run Android studio project on that emulator.also i can start that manually from terminal as well (using `./emulator -avd Nexus_5X_API_24`).

I have already installed JAVA and Gradle.
I have set JAVA_HOME as well

But i cant run IntelliJ project.when i run it,it's showing below error.

[image]

i have installed `gradle-4.0` inside  `/opt/gradle`.but wen i run `gradle -v` it showing `Gradle 2.10`

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Xamarin.Android Proguard - Unsupported class version number 52.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39514518/xamarin-android-proguard-unsupported-class-version-number-52-0)

Comment: This error has nothing to do with the emulator. It comes because you use something from Java 8 while android supports only Java 6.

Comment: try this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/43536258/653856

Comment: @BalázsNemes what is that mean?

Comment: Sorry my knowledge was a bit outdated. So Java 8 is partly supported in the most recent Android version. But is it still not fully supported. I suggest to try the emulator without installing your app. If it launches then the emulator is OK. The error message says it is a language incompatibility error during the build. It does not look like an emulator issue. May be your app uses some java 8 syntax that is not supported. Or you might be use some 3rd party dependency which was built for Java 8.

Comment: i have tried `gradle -v` then it showing `Gradle 2.10` as the result.but i have downloaded and installed `gradle-4.0`.see my updated post

Comment: Your language target for compilation should be 6, not 8.

Comment: run the packager first using: react-native start (go to your project directory and then run this command) and then run your android project.