# Android studio on Ubuntu 17.10 : The emulator process for AVD Nexus_5_API_22 was killed

Tags: android, android-studio

I have reinstalled android-studio 3.0 on my ubuntu. All process installation was ok. Now, I have created a new project. But when I try to run, I get this on the console :

```
11/10 21:10:19: Launching app
Error while waiting for the device: The emulator process for AVD Nexus_5_API_22 was killed.
```

[image]

Any Idea, please?

**Update**
Here is Emulator logs:

```
Executing tasks: [:app:assembleDebug]
Emulator: libGL error: unable to load driver: i965_dri.so
Emulator: libGL error: driver pointer missing
Emulator: libGL error: failed to load driver: i965
Emulator: libGL error: unable to load driver: i965_dri.so
Emulator: libGL error: driver pointer missing
Emulator: libGL error: failed to load driver: i965
Emulator: libGL error: unable to load driver: swrast_dri.so
Emulator: libGL error: failed to load driver: swrast
Emulator: X Error of failed request:  BadValue (integer parameter out of range for operation)
Emulator: Major opcode of failed request:  155 (GLX)
Emulator: Minor opcode of failed request:  24 (X_GLXCreateNewContext)
Emulator: Value in failed request:  0x0
Emulator: Serial number of failed request:  39
Emulator: Current serial number in output stream:  40
Emulator: Process finished with exit code 139 (interrupted by signal 11: SIGSEGV)
```

**Update 2**

I am having the same issue on to different ubuntu 17.10 computer. I use [this](https://developer.android.com/studio/install.html) tutorial for installation

Comment: Try creating a new emulator

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Cannot launch emulator on Linux (Ubuntu 15.10)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35911302/cannot-launch-emulator-on-linux-ubuntu-15-10)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/49125288/5771509

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The path to `libstdc++` has changed in Ubuntu 17.10. Try the following:

```
$ cd ~/Android/Sdk/emulator/lib64/libstdc++
$ mv libstdc++.so.6 libstdc++.so.6.bak
$ ln -s /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6 libstdc++.so.6
```

You should be able to launch the emulator from within Android Studio now.

Answer (score 3):

On Ubuntu 17.10 with Android Studio 3.01. I renamed the library folder ~/Android/Sdk/emulator/lib64/lib/libstdc++ to libstc++.OLD and worked fine.